# How do I resolve the project browser problem in unreal engine? 5

Tags: unreal-engine5

[This is the problem with UE5 I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUa5T.png)

**There is nothing showing up in Unreal Engine 5 Project browser please help????????**

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't add anything to your blank project. If you did, be sure to change the default map in settings, and what map you want to see in that little window.